# How to check Day & month from date which is in Database table

Tags: vb.net

I have problem here...
I want to check Day & month of date which is in database.
There is date field is in database which is mm/dd/yyyy format If I use "select" query then whole Date is access but I want only these date's which having today's day & month 
Example:
if today's date is 02/02/2010 then select only those date whose day is 02 & month is February.(Dont consider Year)

Please be free to ask if you have any problem for understand.

Comment: do you need to check against the current date or some other date?  If it is always the current date then there is already an answer to the question.  If it is some other date (possibly user supplied) then you should use parameters in the query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   *
FROM     {tablename}
WHERE    DAY({datecolumn})=DAY(getdate()) 
AND      MONTH({datecolumn})=MONTH(getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) to pull out the values you're looking for.